# ¿Porque al girar el dispositivo (de portrait a landscape o viceversa) cierra el fragment en el que estoy actualmente?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo una `Activity` que es un `DrawerMenu` (menú lateral), desde el cual hago llamados a diferentes fragments, el problema que tengo es que al acceder a un `Fragment` y girar el dispositivo, cierra el `Fragment` y me regresa a la actividad principal. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esta situación?. De antemano gracias.

Este es el activity del drawer menu (menu lateral):

```
    public class LeftMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener ,SimpleDialog.OnSimpleDialogListener{

    private TextView lblUserN;
    private TextView userEmail;
    private LinearLayout linearMenuLeft;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private Menu menuNav;
    private Global global;
    private int totalFacilitiesFavorites;
    private ArrayList<Facility> facilitiesFavorites;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_left_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        global = new Global();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //seleccionamos por defecto la primera opcion del menu
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        lblUserN =(TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.lblUserN);
        userEmail =(TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
        linearMenuLeft =(LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.linearMenuLeft);

        //recuperar datos de session
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("login_data",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String realName = prefs.getString("realName", "");
        String profilePicture = prefs.getString("profilePicture", "");
        String email = prefs.getString("email", "");

        menuNav = navigationView.getMenu();

    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }else{
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.searchItem) {
            closeOtherFragments();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new SearchFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.loginItem) {
            closeOtherFragments();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_login,new LoginFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.logout) {
            //destruimos los datos de la session
            destroySession();
            MenuItem loginItemMenu = menuNav.findItem(R.id.loginItem);
            loginItemMenu.setVisible(true);

            //refrescamos la activity actual
            global.refreshActualActivity(this);

        } else if (id == R.id.reviewsItem) {
            closeOtherFragments();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_facility_reviews,new UserReviewsFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.favoritesItem) {
            closeOtherFragments();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_facility_favorite,new FacilityFavoriteFragment()).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.toursItem) {
            closeOtherFragments();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_facility_tours,new FacililityToursFragment()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPossitiveButtonClick() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClick() {

    }
}
```

Al girar el dispositivo he notado que el `oncreate` de esta `Activity` vuelve a ejecutarse.

Comment: Puedo ver el código de como cargas el Fragment en tu Activity?

Comment: ok, vale, actualizo mi pregunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto sucede porque al girar el dispositivo se destruye la `Activity` y al crearla nuevamente al inicio no tiene por default un Fragmento, dentro de `onCreate()` debería tener cual es el Fragmento que se tenia originalmente.

una solución rápida seria agregar a tu `Activity` dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` la siguiente propiedad:

```
<activity
            ...
            ...
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

**Esto funciona pero en ocasiones se requiere la destrucción de la Activity porque nuestra aplicación lo requiere, por lo tanto esto ya no aplica.** Por lo tanto otra solución es saber que Fragmento es el último cargado y dentro de `onCreate()` realizar la transacción:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ...
       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          //Realiza la transacción del Fragmento el cual mediante preferencias podemos determinar cual fue el último.
          Fragment fragment = new new myFragment();


          //Realizamos la transacción del Fragmento al iniciar la Activity.
          FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
          ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
          ft.commit();
       }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Elenasys, funciona perfecto :)

Comment: Excellente,estoy editando, agregaré otra solución, ya que en ocasiones en algunas aplicaciones se requiere la destrucción de la Activity....

Comment: vale, gracias Elenasys

Comment: @devjav tengo curiosidad , closeOtherFragments(); que tiene? me parece que no necesitas cerrar los fragmentos, porque se realiza una transacción en la misma Activity, tal vez esto no es necesario.

Comment: ese metodo se encarga de limpiar o cerrar un fragmento el cual quiero reemplazar, por ejemplo, si estoy en el fragment lista y quiero ir al fragment imagenes debo primero quitar el anterioir fragment (lista) para luego ser reemplazado

Comment: Cómo podría saber cuál es el último fragment abierto?

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas Puedes obtener el Fragment que se encuentra en el top de la pila de esta forma: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46784520/250260

Answer (score 1):

Algunas configuraciones de dispositivos pueden cambiar durante el tiempo de ejecución (como, la orientación de la pantalla). Cuando se producen estos cambios, Android reinicia la `Activity` en ejecución (se llama a `onDestroy()` y luego a `onCreate()`).

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) Android explica un poco el proceso que debes seguir para controlar los cambios de orientación o de configuración.

Para solventar esto y capturar los cambios de configuración se puede hacer los siguiente:

**Manifest**

En él se puede declarar los cambios que quieres controlar mediante la etiqueta android:configChanges, quedando la declaración de la actividad de la siguiente forma:

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppThemeAction" />
```

**Activity**

Se puede poner un código para recoger los eventos de cambio de configuración como puede ser el cambio de orientación de la pantalla y se pueden realizar operaciones si se desea, el código es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    //detectamos el cambio de orientación en este caso
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        landscape = true;
        //acciones deseadas
    }

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        landscape = false;
        //acciones deseadas
    }
}
```